# TextView keeps appearing behind ListView

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

I've been looking a lot at ListViews in previous answers, but I can't seem to find a solution to my problem. Primarily, despite successfully retrieving an array of data from an SQLite database, the TextView from when there is no data remains visible even when the list is successfully populated.

I'm trying to show previous user inputs in a history activity as follows:

HistoryActivity.java

```
public class HistoryActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

    // progress bar
    // Create a progress bar to display while the list loads
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
    progressBar.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    getListView().setEmptyView(progressBar);

    // Must add the progress bar to the root of the layout
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    root.addView(progressBar);

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            array);
    setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

activity_history.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Nothing saved. Try to answer some questions now!"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

From previous SO answers, I've ensured the ids in the .xml file are correct, and from what I understand, when extending the ListActivity, you don't need to use a .setEmptyView().

I've likely missed out something basic, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I did't understand your problem properly ... what I got is when the List become fill with items then still the Text view remains visible.

- I think you just get Reference of the TextView

  TextView emptyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty);
- then check if (list.size > 0)

  make the textView invisible

  emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
- else make it visible setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: I implemented `TextView emptyView = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
        if (array.length > 0) {
            emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }`
But to no avail. The TextView meant for when the list is empty continues to appear even when the list is populated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `setVisibility="gone"` to the textView if your list is not empty and show it if your list is empty.